# Using a callback with Google Fusion Tables

Tags: javascript, callback, google-fusion-tables

I'm using javascript to query [this](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1QT0Fw78l_lapmNqEcOOJQkgCyPd9QEA20cZyftc) google fusion table, and don't understand how to return the values from my function.

```
function fusionTableQuery(){    
    var result;
    var queryurl = "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=";    
    var sql = "SELECT+City+FROM+2175264+WHERE+Population>200000"; 
    var querytail = "&jsonCallback=?";        
    var jqxhr=$.get(queryurl + sql + querytail, result = 
                function queryHandler(data) {   // display retrieved data    
                    console.log(data.table.rows);
                    return data.table.rows;
                }
                , "jsonp") 

    return result;

}
```

I am able to see in the `console.log()` output the values that I want to see, but I don't have a clear understanding about the callback works.

What I want is to store the result of my query in a variable, similar to the following:

```
cities = fusionTableQuery()
```

Can you help me better understand how to achieve this? I'm having difficulty understand how a callback should be working here. Alternatively, I would be just as happy to not use use a callback here if it is not required.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you could do it:

```
var cities;

function createSidebar(searchStr) {
  //searchStr is your query -> SELECT * FROM table ...

  var queryText = encodeURIComponent(searchStr);
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryText);

  query.send(getData); //set the callback function
}

function getData(response) {
 cities = response.getDataTable();     
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bassam - with this approach though, I can't tell when the query has returned a value for later calculations. Perhaps this is also a problem with my original suggested approach.

Comment: @celenius do you wanna know if your query returned rows? if so, you can use cities.getNumberOfRows() == 0

Comment: I want to figure out when the value is returned from the fusion table;  I suppose this means that I just call the subsequent functions from within the callback `getData()`

Comment: @celenius exactly .. or ur getData could hold the code for whatever you wanna do with the data. essentially getData being called is how you figure out that the query returned data